# wordpress admin keep reloading after migrating site to subdomain

Tags: wordpress

I migrated wordpress site to a subdomain dev.****.com to keep a dev version of website.I changed the domain in the wp-settings file to the subdomain and in the database. The site is working fine but when I go to admin page, the page keeps loading. In the console, i get the error

> Mixed Content: The page at https://***/admin' was loaded over HTTPS,
> but requested an insecure script
> 'http://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php'. This request has
> been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

The original site is working perfectly fine and doesnt show any error.why on the subdomain i am getting this error?

Comment: You can't load non-https resources if you are using https. Change the asset to `https://cdn.jsinit.directfwd.com/sk-jspark_init.php`. If the CDN doesn't have HTTPS enabled then you can always self-host the library or use another CDN

Comment: The main site at the domain is working fine without any errors though!

Comment: Did you update the site url in the configs to reflect the subdomain?

Comment: can u plz elaborate. If you are referring to adding these lines in wp-config.php then i did. 
define('WP_HOME','dev.***.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','dev.***.com');

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-your-wordpress-site-urls-step-by-step/